# How to make non blocking call in init_by_lua

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

```
init_worker_by_lua_block {
  ....
  ngx.timer.every(10, MyFunction)
}

function MyFunction()
  local response = requests.get { url = url, headers = h }. 
  ...
```

Where MyFunction makes http request via "requests".  This blocks the incoming request every 10 seconds. How to make this non blocking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you use [lua-resty-requests](https://github.com/tokers/lua-resty-requests) library.

In timer context, lua-resty-requests uses non blocking cosocket API, so it shouldn't block.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. I was using Lua-requests